# downloading in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

getting error while casting IActionResult to Task Asynch,its a given Project,i m editing some parts .

```
public IActionResult Download(int id)
        {
            int documentId = (int)id;
            var userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId"));
            var status = _documentService.DocumentPermissionRule(userId, documentId);
            if (status) {
                string filePath = _documentService.GetPath(userId, documentId);
                string fileName = _documentService.GetName(userId, documentId);
                
                return (IActionResult)ReturnDocumentFileAsync(filePath, fileName);
                
            } else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Docuement permission failed";
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Both Methods ARE in Controller only

```
 public async Task<FileResult> ReturnDocumentFileAsync(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(
                            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                            "wwwroot\\Documents\\", fileName
                           );

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));

        }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

just changed

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync(int id)
        {
            int documentId = (int)id;
            var userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId"));
            var status = _documentService.DocumentPermissionRule(userId, documentId);
            if (status) {
                string filePath = _documentService.GetPath(userId, documentId);
                string fileName = _documentService.GetName(userId, documentId);
              return   await ReturnDocumentFileAsync(filePath, fileName);
               
                
            } else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Docuement permission failed";
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index") ;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).